# how to pull branch directly to another machine while github is down

Tags: git, github

When GitHub goes down, `git pull` no longer works because everyone on the team uses it as a centralized repo. It seems like we should be able to set another machine to upstream though and pull directly from them. How do we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add another remote, e.g.

```
git remote add other git@other-host:repo.git
```

Then you can pull or push from it, e.g.

```
git pull other master
git push other master
```

If you're working within the team, you can pull directly from your colleagues hosts by adding their remote by IP, so you don't have to rely on GitHub. E.g.

```
git remote add John username@192.168.0.123:/path/to/repo
```

To achieve that, make sure you've proper SSH access to their machines.